# How do i completly remove ubuntu 12.04 from my laptop?

Tags: 12.04

I need to delete Ubuntu 12.04 from my computer (windows 7 64 bit), is it possible?
How can i delete it? I coundn't find Ubuntu on add or remove programs in windows.

Answer (score 3):

**Delete Ubuntu**

Boot live cd/usb of ubuntu, type gparted into the terminal, turn the Linux partition [ext4] and swap etc. into NTFS and format.

**Remove Grub**

Boot from the Windows CD, enter the recovery console press R when it asks you whether you want to install windows etc. When you're at the console, type:

fixmbr

and that will remove GRUB from your system.

[Got the grub bit from here](http://www.ntcompatible.com/How_to_remove_GRUB_loader_t28242.html)

**Fix Partitions**

You might be able to try and extend your original windows partition over the old Ubuntu ones, but that might be dangerous territory. Otherwise you would have to reformat windows partition. Don't forget to make a full back up of your windows.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Windows CD, enter the recovery console press R when it asks you whether you want to install windows etc. When you're at the console, type:

```
Bootrec.exe/fixmbr
Bootrec.exe/fixboot
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to first remove the grub installer and then to format the partition and then use the partition as NTFS. By this way you will not only remove the ubuntu but also make that free space available to windows.
**Note :** *Ubuntu uses EXT file system which windows does not support. So you will have to convert EXT file system to NTFS to make it usable for windows.*

Comment: How do you convert an ext3 or ext4 filesystem to NTFS?

Comment: by formatting it and then specifying  the NTFS file system instead of EXT 3